# Проблема с кириллицей в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, кириллица

Пытаюсь выполнить поиск подстроки, но с кириллицей возникают проблемы.

```
select * from `posts` where "Текст" LIKE CONCAT("%", `substr_ru`, "%");
```

Данный запрос по какой-то причине выводит мне абсолютно все записи в которых `substr_ru` является пустой строкой и полностью игнорирует содержимое "Текст".

В то время, как с латиницей все работает без проблем.

```
select * from `posts` where "Text" LIKE CONCAT("%", `substr_en`, "%");
```

Точно такое же поведение наблюдается и у функций `instr` и `position`. С остальными операторами кириллица работает адекватно, например:

```
select * from `posts` where "Текст" = substr_ru;
```

Comment: Использовать `N` перед литералом?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а как можно добавить N для результата, который пришел из функции concat?

Comment: Что-то типа `CONCAT(N'%', N'substr', N'%')`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, если бы все было так просто, то и конкатенация не понадобилась. Нужно ведь добавить к `substr_ru`, а не просто к строке. Может быть есть какие-то аналоги для N, которые умеют это делать с полями? Поиск не приводит к результатам.